# Java: Maze icons: what to do?

Tags: java

I'm a complete noob in java. I still really don't know how to code.
I am having a problem in my maze. I can now go from start(2) to end(3) but the problem is  the icon for (start). I tried to print out the values of our maze (mazePlan) and it was fine. The only problem is the icon. The icons changed only after the recursive function is finished ( I used setIcons). I need to get those icon for start move. Thanks! i really need some help. Thanks!

```
 class solveButton implements ActionListener{
    private boolean goal;
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e1)
    {  
        int i,j, a = 0,b = 0;
        goal = false;

        //Find 2/start
        for(i = 0; i<10; i++){
            for ( j = 0; j<10; j++){
                if (getMazePlan()[i][j] == 2){
                    a= i; b = j;
                }       
            }
        }   

        function(a,b);

        //print only
        for (i=0;i<10;i++){
            for(j = 0; j < 10; j++){
                System.out.print(getMazePlan()[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }

    public void function(int y, int x){

        int ctr = 0,b ,a;

        //CHECKING FOR WALLS
        //LEFT
            if(x-1 >= 0 && x-1 <= 9){
                if(getMazeBoolean()[y][x-1] == false) 
                    ctr++;
            }
        //UP
            if(y-1 >= 0 && y-1 <= 9){
                if(getMazeBoolean()[y-1][x] == false) 
                    ctr++;
            }
        //RIGHT
            if(x+1 >= 0 && x+1 <= 9){
                if(getMazeBoolean()[y][x+1] == false) 
                    ctr++;
            }
        //DOWN
            if(y+1 >= 0 && y+1 <= 9){
                if(getMazeBoolean()[y+1][x] == false) 
                    ctr++;
            }

        try{
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }catch(Exception e){}

            //print only
        System.out.println("Move");
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
                System.out.print(getMazePlan()[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        stack1.push(x);
        stack1.push(y);
        setMazePlan1(0, y, x);
        maze[y][x].setIcon(end);
        setMazeBoolean(true, y , x);


        //LEFT
        if(ctr > 0 && goal == false){
        if(x-1 >= 0 && x-1 <= 9){
            if(getMazeBoolean()[y][x-1] == false && getMazePlan()[y][x-1] != 3){
                setMazePlan1(2, y, x-1);
                function(y, x-1);
                ctr--;

                if(ctr != 0  && goal == false){
                    b = stack1.pop();
                    a = stack1.pop();
                    setMazePlan1(2, b , a);
                    stack1.push(a);
                    stack1.push(b);

                    try{
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }catch(Exception e){}

                    setMazePlan1(0, b , a);
                }
            }
            else if(getMazePlan()[y][x-1] == 3){
                System.out.println("FINISH");
                goal = true;
            }
        }
        }
        //UP
        if(ctr > 0 && goal == false){
        if(y-1 >= 0 && y-1 <= 9){
            if(getMazeBoolean()[y-1][x] == false && getMazePlan()[y-1][x] != 3){
                setMazePlan1(2, y-1, x);
                function(y-1, x);
                ctr--;

            if(ctr != 0  && goal == false){
                b = stack1.pop();
                a = stack1.pop();
                setMazePlan1(2, b , a);
                stack1.push(a);
                stack1.push(b);

                try{
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }catch(Exception e){}

                setMazePlan1(0, b , a);
            }
            }
            else if(getMazePlan()[y-1][x] == 3){
                System.out.println("FINISH");
                goal = true;
            }
        }
        }
        //RIGHT
        if(ctr > 0 && goal == false){
        if(x+1 >= 0 && x+1 <= 9){
            if(getMazeBoolean()[y][x+1] == false && getMazePlan()[y][x+1] != 3 ){
                setMazePlan1(2, y, x+1);
                function(y, x+1);
                ctr--;

            if(ctr != 0  && goal == false){
                b = stack1.pop();
                a = stack1.pop();
                setMazePlan1(2, b , a);
                stack1.push(a);
                stack1.push(b);

                try{
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }catch(Exception e){}

                setMazePlan1(0, b , a);
            }
            }
            else if(getMazePlan()[y][x+1] == 3){
                System.out.println("FINISH");
                goal = true;
            }
        }
        }
        //DOWN
        if(ctr > 0 && goal == false){
        if(y+1 >= 0 && y+1 <= 9){
            if(getMazeBoolean()[y+1][x] == false && getMazePlan()[y+1][x] != 3){
                setMazePlan1(2, y+1, x);
                function(y+1, x);
                ctr--;

            if(ctr != 0  && goal == false){
                b = stack1.pop();
                a = stack1.pop();
                setMazePlan1(2, b , a);
                stack1.push(a);
                stack1.push(b);

                try{
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }catch(Exception e){}

                setMazePlan1(0, b , a);
            }
            }
            else if(getMazePlan()[y+1][x] == 3){
                System.out.println("FINISH");
                goal = true;
            }
        }
        }
        //DEADEND
        if(goal == false && ctr == 0){

            b = stack1.pop();
            a = stack1.pop();
            setMazePlan1(0, b , a);
            try{
            b = stack1.pop();
            a = stack1.pop();
            stack1.push(a);
            stack1.push(b);
            setMazePlan1(2, b , a);
            }
            catch(Exception e){

            }

            try{
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }catch(Exception e){}

            //print only
            System.out.println("Pop");
            for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
                    System.out.print(getMazePlan()[i][j] + " ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            } 
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply.
I read about Swing Timers and tried to used it. And it works! :) yay ! thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling
`Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.
See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Without trying to decipher your hauge chunk of code, sounds like to need to force a redraw/paint after you have set the icon.

There isn't actually enough code here to know what to call repaint()...

You might also want to have a look at Java GUI apps / GUI threads (i.e. you shouldn't do all your "maze" stuff on the GUI thread if it can take a while)

Comment: sorry for the codes... tried to repaint the icon, panel and frame, still doesn't work